# WordPress : 301 redirection not working

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I am using the following code to redirect a dynamic URL to a new dynamic URL, under the same domain in wordpress:

```
RewriteRule ^view-company/?id=(.+?)&name=(.+?)$ view-company/$1/$2/? [L,R=301,NC]
```

I want to redirect https://www.mydomains.com/view-company/id=1&name=abc to https://www.mydomains.com/view-company/1/abc

But this is not redirecting me to new url. Please help me.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not match against query strings in RewriteRule's pattern, you need to match against `%{QUERY_STRING}` Variable using a `RewriteCond`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([^&]+)&name=([^&]+)$
RewriteRule ^view-company/?$ https://www.mydomains.com/view-company/%1/%2? [L,R=301]
```

You can also manipulate querystrings using `%{THE_REQUEST}` Variable

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /view-company/\?id=([^&]+)&name=([^&\s]+)
RewriteRule ^ https://www.mydomains.com/view-company/%1/%2? [L,R=301]
```